# Adding ORDER BY on a CASE statement

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm learning SQL (beginner), one of the concepts is CASES and this put me in a bit of a pickle. I have this database:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

| pokedex_num | pokemon_name | evolution_line | evolution_line_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BULBASAUR | BULBASAUR | 1 |
| 2 | IVYSAUR | BULBASAUR | 2 |
| 3 | VENUSAUR | BULBASAUR | 3 |
| 1 | SQUIRTLE | SQUIRTLE | 1 |
| 2 | WARTORTLE | SQUIRTLE | 2 |
| 3 | BLASTOISE | SQUIRTLE | 3 |

And I have to convert it to this table:

| firsevolution | secondevolution | thirdevolution |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BULBASAUR | IVYSAUR | VENUSAUR |
| SQUIRTLE | WARTORTLE | BLASTOISE |

Took me a while but I managed to do it by adding MAX to my CASE statements to avoid the NULLS. However, I'm having issues when I now try to add an ORDER BY pokedex_num, the NULLS return.

Would appreciate an explanation as to why it's behaving that way?

Here is my current attempt:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN evolution_line_number = 1 THEN pokemon_name END) AS baseform
, MAX(CASE WHEN evolution_line_number = 2 THEN pokemon_name END) AS secondevolution
, MAX(CASE WHEN evolution_line_number = 3 THEN pokemon_name END) as thirdevolution
 FROM training.pokemon
 GROUP BY evolution_line, pokedex_num
 ORDER BY pokedex_num
```

| firsevolution | secondevolution | thirdevolution |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BULBASAUR | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | IVYSAUR | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | VENUSAUR |
| SQUIRTLE | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | WARTORTLE | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | BLASTOISE |

Comment: Show us your current attempt.

Comment: Note that sample data and expected result should be consistent. Where did CATERPIE come from?

Comment: Use `order by min(pokedex_num)`. However, it depends on the rest of your query. Please Edit your Question and show us what you have so far.

Comment: Caterpie is further down, but it's there! Also uploaded my current attempt.

Comment: Please [do not post images of data or code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: The whole purpose in grouping is to eliminate the row numbers and collapse to a single row. You need to group only on `evolution_line`. And because the column is no longer available to is won't be able to order on it either.

Comment: Yeah that's where I was having issues. I thought I had the exercise covered until I realized there was a reqt for me to order by pokedex num.

Answer (score 0):

You current query returns `NULL`'s not because of the `order by`, but because `GROUP BY evolution_line, pokedex_num`, and pokedex nums are different pokemons.

I would consider using two self joins in case you want to use columns of initial table, other then names.

For example:

```sql
select t1.pokedex_num, t1.pokemon_name l1, t2.pokemon_name l2, t3.pokemon_name l3 from ta t1
left join ta t2 on t2.evolution_line = t1.evolution_line and t2.evolution_line_number = 2
left join ta t3 on t3.evolution_line = t1.evolution_line and t3.evolution_line_number = 3
where t1.evolution_line_number = 1
Order by t1.pokedex_num
```

Demo can be seen [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/tV7mkksx).